# Mysql Connector crash on SQL Server 2008

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

I would like to create a linked Server betwenn my MYSQL Server and a SQL Server 2008. I already installed the MYSQL Connector ODBC drivers 5.1 (previously the 5.3 Version but same problem) on my SQL Server 2008 (Virtual Machine, 64-Bit). I would to create a New System DNS in the ODBC Data Source Administrator Menu. Furthermore I enter the Connection Data from the MYSQL Server (IP-Adress, User, Password, etc.) and hit "Test". After I hit "Test" I get a few seconds later "No Response" and the Mysql Connector Window crashes. Do you know any solution or anything that I can do, to solve this issue? Thanks in Advance.

/edit:
After some testing I get finally an error Message with the Result:

```
Connection Failed: [08S01] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

Does this help?

Comment: After some testing I get finally an error Message with the Result:

Comment: Could you please include things that you tried for solving this issue? Are you sure about firewall exception?

Comment: @triplus It seems you found a solution on your own. Great! [Please put that as an answer and not as an edit in your question and accept your own answer](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Ports weren't forwarded in the firewall. IT-Department forwarded two Ports on the SQL-Server. Sadly, I dont know which one. Know it works. If anyone has the same problem and sees no Error Message, try to perform a right click and the error message should be visible.